# xml or normal file for creating a reference file

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax, stax

I want to create a reference file its skelton is as follows:

```
cityname=...
id=.... lat=... lon=...
targetfile=...
```

so that the input I receive from the user is just the lat and lon. and then I
 the I should give the user the name of the target file.

my question is,should I create the reference file as normal file or as xml.
Note: the reference file may contain numerous lines.

Comment: both have pros and cons, get input from your user and know how he is comfortable to consume data. I personally suggest XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal file

- Fast (to develop that is)
- Simple
- Requires hand made logic if you want to do anything special with it
- You can't easily check if the file is well formed or not

XML file

- Slower to develop
- More complicated especially if you're not used to working with XML
- Plenty of ready made code to help you process your file
- You can create an XML schema to make sure that the file is well formed

Comment: concerning the last point you stated regarding the normal file You can't easily check if the file is well formed", i think you meant "You can't easily check if the file is NOT well formed", right?

Comment: It's the same thing. Checking whether it's well-formed or not is the exact same operation.